# Updating the coordinates in d3js for a tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treeview, visualization

I am currently using the d3.layout.tree() to compute the positions of my data.

```
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .sort(null)
        .size([size.height, size.width - maxLabelLength * options.fontSize])
        .children(function(d)
        {
            return (!d.contents || d.contents.length === 0) ? null : d.contents;
        });
```

Initially I compute and add my nodes like this:

```
var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData);
var nodeGroup = layoutRoot.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name })
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d)
        {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });
nodeGroup.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("class", "node-dot")
    .attr("r", options.nodeRadius);
```

Now I add a new node to the treeData and also to the layoutRoot:

```
var grp = layoutRoot.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name })
    .enter()
    .append('svg:g')
    .attr("transform", function (d)
    {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    })

grp.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("class", "node-dot")
    .attr("r", options.nodeRadius)
```

The problem is now, that the newly computed nodes that are already present in the rootLayout have different x,y coordinates after having added a new node. But they are not within the enter() or exit() selection and are thus not redrawn at their correct position. How is this supposed to be handled, ie. how should the position of the nodes that have not changed anything but their coordinates be updated/refreshed?

I a noob to d3js. So don't be too harsh :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the `enter()` selection from the update of nodes like this :

```
var nodeGroup = layoutRoot.selectAll("g.node")
.data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name });

// Enter selection
nodeGroup.enter()
.append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "node")

// Update
nodeGroup.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
});

var nodeDots = layoutRoot.selectAll("g.node-dot")
.data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name });

// Enter
nodeDots.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "node-dot")

// Update
nodeDots.attr("r", options.nodeRadius);
```

Hope this helps, but in a general way of speaking, it is perhaps easier to code this way, with separation of enter and updates (see [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) for more info)

Comment: The variables "nodeGroup" and "nodeDots" are still pointing at the enter() selection.  If you want the complete update selection you need  to assign the result of data() to, for example, nodeGroup and then use nodeGroup.enter() to get at the enter selection and nodeGroup to get at the update selection.